# ClickOnce cannot find its prerequisites while the files are at the place they have to be

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I want to publish my application using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) with some prerequisites (.NET 4.5 and [SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express)).

I did as it says in *[How to: Include Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130(v=vs.110).aspx)* (note that the package folders were at `v8.1A` folder instead of `v8A` folder), but it still says it can't find the files. I've tried both [Visual Studio 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2013) and [Visual Studio 2015](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2015) RC.

> To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' for item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.
>
> To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.
>
> To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.
>
> To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'DotNetFX40ClientKB2468871\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe' for item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64) and Update for .NET Framework 4 (KB2468871)' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.

Comment: I think you should go to your set up and check any prenrequisites required by your application. Add the packages to be locally so they download with the package if necesarry but from your installation.

Comment: Humm let me check in my computer, sorry my english is not perfect :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a very wrong idea about what is possible in a ClickOnce deployment.  The canonical MSDN page is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  High-lighting the most significant sections in that web page:

> **Impact to the user's computer**. With Windows Installer deployment, applications often rely on shared components, with the potential for versioning conflicts; with ClickOnce deployment, each application is self-contained and cannot interfere with other applications.
>   **Security permissions**. Windows Installer deployment requires administrative permissions and allows only limited user installation; ClickOnce deployment enables non-administrative users to install and grants only those Code Access Security permissions necessary for the application.
>   **Does not affect shared components or other applications**: Yes
>   **Installation of shared files**: No
>   **Installation to Global Assembly Cache**: No
>   **Installation for multiple users**: No
>   **Install time registry access**: Limited

These intentional restrictions were designed to make users feel good about installing .NET programs with ClickOnce.  They don't need assistance from an administrator to get the program installed.  And the installer cannot make drastic changes to the machine, the kind that cause other programs to malfunction.  A very, very common problem with installers.

This is grossly incompatible with what you are trying to do.  Both the .NET Framework and SQL Express *are* shared components and *do* require administrator access to install and *do* risk destabilizing a machine that already has .NET or SQL server installed.

So this simply cannot work.  You *can* select them as Prerequisites but all that happens at install time is that the ClickOnce installer verifies that they are met.  In other words, the machine must already have the correct versions of .NET and SQL Express installed.  If it doesn't then the deployment will fail and the user gets the dialog that tells him where to download the installer.  It is then entirely up to him (or his administrator) to download and run the installer.  After which your ClickOnce install completes without trouble.

The deployment wizard is fairly crummy, it should have hidden the radio buttons at the bottom.  Only "from the component vendor's web site" is a valid selection for these prerequisites.  The bootstrapper .xml file format isn't sophisticated enough to limit the selection.

Only way to get ahead if you want to provide the user with these prerequisites included with the installer is to create a normal MSI installer.

Comment: Visual Studio will build a ClickOnce Setup.exe that runs prerequisites on initial install to a target computer. This is a separate install from the ".application" deployment, and is capable of installing new software in addition to verifying prerequisites.

Comment: Just add your own answer to explain to the OP why he doesn't have a real problem.

Comment: The OP does have a real issue. I'm responding to the implication in this accepted response that ClickOnce can't/shouldn't handle Windows Installer-style prerequisites on install. Said prerequisites may required elevation in order to run, but that doesn't prevent the ClickOnce infrastructure from being used to install them, and this feature can be quite handy, especially for enterprise internal deployments.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this scenario in the past is just to use the built in "publish" features.  They seem to work well in my experience.

In the Publish configuration section of your application there is a "Prerequisites" button that you can click and check off .NET Framework and SQL Express, among other things.  During the ClickOnce install, it will prompt the user to pull them down from Microsoft before installing your application.[image: Application Properties]

[image: Prerequisites Selection]

Comment: you are downloading the prerequisites from the component vendor's web site while I want to download them from the same location as my application since I don't want to make my clients download anything.